# Grails database migrations MySQL issue - changelog not generated

Tags: mysql, grails, database-migration

I tried running database migration on grails 2.2.1 but it seams not to be working.

Running *dbm-generate-changelog* generated initial changelog.groovy, but trying to run *dbm-gorm-diff* after model changes results in no file being generated.

Last line that is logged back from Liquibase is:

```
Sequences not supported for .....
```

My datasource is set properly and mysql dialect is set to *org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect*

I tried to find a configuration option to specify directly to liquibase that mysql is target, but it seams that it reads it from datasource.

Any ideas?

[SOLVED] - UPDATE 
There is an issue associated with this http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-120

As a workaround you can clone https://github.com/ph4t/grails-database-migration and then point to the cloned project from your grails application (BuildConfig.groovy) by using>

```
grails.plugin.location.'database-migration' = "<path to cloned folder>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue associated with this http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-120

As a workaround you can clone https://github.com/ph4t/grails-database-migration and then point to the cloned project from your grails application (BuildConfig.groovy) by using>

```
grails.plugin.location.'database-migration' = "<path to cloned folder>"
```